# what will the slope of mean vs std tell us?

Tags: statistics, variance, slope, mean-square-error, noise

I might be asking something very basic here with this question.
I have ND:YAG laser system and I would like to evaluate shot to shot noise from laser. To evaluate this, I take a set of 500 images of a homogeneously mixed dye solution. I calculate standard deviation to estimate variance of intensity variation from shot to shot (i.e. for each image). I plotted std vs mean intensity for each image. I see a positive slope from this plot. How do I infer this trend (positive slope) and what will the slope (∂(µ)/∂(std)) of this plot provide me